# React.js best workflow for multiple independent modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build

I just wondering let's say I already have a website. If I would like to inject some react modules into it lets say MODULE-A, MODULE-B, MODULE-C. At some situations, MODULE-A and MODULE-B are on the same page. All modules are sharing `react`, `axios` but also they have their own dependencies. what is actually the best approach to prepare build for it?? I actually like `create-react-app`. Is there any smart way to make modules only load required dependencies? so I can include them separately and if both exist on the page they will not clone dependency in code.

I want to avoid the situation that I have 20 small modules and all of them use react inside built code. So 60% of the code will be duplicated dependencies.

Comment: make them node modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not many options

You can leverage code-splitting as referred here https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ so let's say you have

```
ModuleA -> [depA, depB, depC]
ModuleB -> [depA]
ModuleC -> [depC]
```

now you can code split to 4 javascript files which will be

```
moduleAbundle.js
mobuleBbundle.js
mobuleCbundle.js
vendors.js
```

vedors will be concatenation of `depA, depB, depC` but ofcourse when you will load moduleB and ModuleC on 1 page you will be also loading depB as it's included in `vendors.js` you will need to think and play a lot with orchestration of this.

But what you can actually do you can think of most critical parts and most shared deps and list them, let's say all of your packages are using `react`, `react-dom`, `lodash` you will make bundle for `vendors` with only those libraries, any other library will be bundled with module itself and yes you can't 100% elimate "double-loading" but if you will double load library which has several kB it's fine, when it's larger, ship it with `vendors.js`

or you can have some complex mechanism on backend side when you will exactly specify and orchestrate loaded dependencies because you know which modules are rendered and what are they dependencies. But there are no any ways of `on-the-fly` bundling and sending only needed and requested dependencies, it would be very slow to do that on-the-fly and you need to flush quick response to the browser not slow it down with additional compilation process. So it's most likely a manual job to correctly prepare and split code in logical chunks which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know answer for React but for the future, maybe you can think about using Angular instead, and its ngModule capability into splitting application to multiple independent modules with their own dependences.

https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules